# blender 2.93 Shading Selecting Texture node all other nodes vanish

Tags: node-editor, shader-nodes

blender 2.93

1. Default "General" scene 2)Shading Tab
   Spacebar (or "Add") a "Texture" node and all the default nodes disappear. Then all options to create new nodes are not available. Undo does not work. Workaround Creating a New scene and starting over and *not* adding a texture node.
   Adding other nodes does not cause this issue.
   [image: texture node]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You've gone to a different editor space, here.  You can switch back to the *Shader Editor* with the top left button.

[image]

You instead want to pick a type of texture, they are all separate nodes listed under the option you picked.  (I'm not sure why that option is there, I don't get it on 2.93.1)